# Precisely measuring time in presence of optimization

Tags: java, optimization, time

```
long start = System.nanoTime ();           // 1
//whatever operations                      // 2
long elapsed = System.nanoTime () - start; // 3
```

Is it possible that statements 1 and 3 are shuffled together so that we cannot measure time precisely?

--------------thanks for all feedbacks, let's change the code to:

```
long start = System. currentTimeMillis ();           // 1
try { Thread.sleep (1000); } catch (Exception e) {}  // 2
long elapsed = System. currentTimeMillis () - start; // 3
```

and change the question to: can execution of 1 2 3 be reordered to 1 3 2 ? 
If so, how can we measure how long 2 takes?

Comment: What do you mean by "shuffled together", exactly?

Comment: What's most likely is that the operation you're measuring isn't at all "typical" since you're not using the result, or you're not running it in the context of a larger program.  So the measurement will be meaningless.  Also, you will fail to account for the time spent inside nanoTime.

Comment: A nano second is really a short time for any application. If you need more accuracy maybe Java is not the right platform.

Comment: @PeterMmm - But there's no guarantee that nanoTime returns nanosecond precision.  In fact, it's pretty much guaranteed not to.

Comment: In terms of "shuffled" operations, Java does require that all data references and operation side-effects occur in the stated order.  But this doesn't require that the actual time-consuming, non-side-effect-generating operations occur in stated order.

Comment: @PeterMmm, if you just new an object in statement 2, you can tell that a nano second isn't too short for Java, or even for any application.

Comment: You won't be able to measure such a short time realiable. Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) about accuracy of `nanoTime()`.

Comment: @user2081147: `nanoTime()` returns its result with nanosecond resolution but it does *not* have nanosecond precision - not on any current hardware...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you were not calling `System.nanotTime()`, neither the JVM or the CPU would not reorder those instructions because you are using `start` in the expression assigned to `elapsed`. In any case, `System.nanoTime()` is bound to generate a native system call which would prevent reordering.

That said, for any time measurement of this kind to make any sense I would expect that whatever is between the calls to `System.nanoTime()` would consist of at least several hundred thousand instructions so that reordering would be impossible anyway.

If the timed code is too short, the inherent precision issues of any computer timer - including the high resolutions timers provided by some operating systems - will make it impossible to produce a usable timing result.

Comment: is that possible 1 2 3 is reordered to 1 3 2, if statement 2 has nothing to do with start? If so, how can we measure the time used by 2?

Comment: @user2081147: my instinct and experience says that 1,2,3 cannot be reordered, due to the sideffects of `nanoTime()` being a native call, but I cannot find the actual reference in the JLS. Are you seeing a specific issue, or is this discussion academic?

Comment: Calls cannot be reordered.

Comment: @HotLicks: 1. I believe that it is possible for inlined *Java* method calls to be essentially reordered, if there are no side-effects. 2. I think that the OP is essentially asking whether `System.nanoTime()` acts as a barrier or not. I believe that it does...

Comment: @thkala, I have been optimizing a piece of code and I saw <5 ms after future.get(25, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) in my logs; so I came to this question.

Comment: @HotLicks: there is no "happen before" between 2 and 3.

Comment: @thkala - Due in part to the ordering issues, Java methods are hardly ever inlined by javac.  JIT compilers, on the other hand, inline quite a bit but rigorously observe the ordering rules (for which there are some fairly grueling tests in the Java verification test suite).

Comment: @thkala, I just found that my previous comment was too confusing...whatever, you have already got the essence of the question. Your abstraction is more clear than my original question.